# Can't understand where is the problem (Java)

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, noclassdeffounderror

Trying to run a program that swaps names. The task is simple: input > Alice Bob Alex, output > Alex Bob Alice 
P.s. Maybe the problem is stupid, but I just recently started programming, so I don't know what to do

I try to run the code in Eclipse - gives an index error. I start in the console - gives an error of the main name. Tried to pass through the internal debugger in Eclipse - writes that I am using obsolete methods. In the end, nothing is clear./

```
public class Noob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print(args[2]);
        System.out.print(" " + args[1]);
        System.out.println(" " + args[0]);
    }
}
```

1. Error message from Eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 0
    at noob/noob.Noob.main(Noob.java:7)

2. Console (the file name is Noob.java)

   1. First I compiled src file (> javac Noob.java)
   2. Then I ran it (> java Noob)

Error: Could not find or load main class Noob
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: noob/Noob (wrong name: Noob)

Comment: You're running it wrong. It's expecting you to pass three arguments. You can probably edit some kind of run configuration in Eclipse to specify the arguments.

Comment: Eclipse can pass in arguments to the application. Click on "Run\Run Configuration" then under _Arguments_ you can pass in a list of names (whitespace separated). Since you're not doing that, the array _args_ is empty, thus throwing index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass three arguments

This is the steps you need to follow, to passing arguments

1-) Click on Run -> Run Configurations

2-) Click on Arguments tab

3-) In Program Arguments section , Enter your arguments.

4-) Click Apply

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing correctly the values to your program. If you call the program from command line with `java myProgram Alice Bob Alex` your code should work.

Moreover, you can pass the values to your code through Eclipse directly inside Run Configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it would be better to not hard code the values. Try this:

```
for (int i=args.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    System.out.print(args[i] + ' ');
}
System.out.println("");
```